# StackOverflowError when deserializing binary data into objects

Tags: java, coldfusion, stack-overflow, coldfusion-9

Using ColdFusion 9.0.1 on Windows I run into the following problem.

I've got some pretty big and complex objects (with nested objectcts with nested structs with nested object ...etc) serialized to binary data so I can put it into my database. This works like a charm but when I retrieve such binary data from my database and then try to deserialize the data using the `objectLoad()` function, I get a stack overlfow error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Exception.(Exception.java:77)
at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.(InvocationTargetException.java:54)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:47)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
at
```

Repeat some more!!!!

```
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1030)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyWrapper.readExternal(TemplateProxyWrapper.java:48)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(ObjectInputStream.java:1792)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1351)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1251)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager._executeHQL(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:822)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.executeHQL(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:751)
    at coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernatePersistenceManager.executeQueryWithNamedParams(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:626)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils._executeQuery(ORMUtils.java:332)
    at coldfusion.orm.ORMUtils.executeQuery(ORMUtils.java:320)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ORMExecuteQuery(CFPage.java:7805)
```

There's no infinite loop or anything because when I increase the stack size in my JVM settings it all works just fine. I don't want to increase my stack size on my production server however.

**So does anybody know a way to deserialize binary data into objects without creating such a huge stack?**

Comment: Create a less nested object structure.  The levels of nesting reflects the complexity of the structure of the object. If you have a collection like a tree you can write your own custom serialization which can optmise how the data is traversed.  This simplest solution may be to increase the maximum stack size.

Comment: I know, but the data is already in the database you see.

Comment: In that case you need a larger stack to read the data. I am surprised you were able to write the objects because usually you need about the same stack size.

Comment: That is surprising now that you mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the only way to solve this was to increase the stack size of the JVM or to refactor my objects.